# Present progressive vs shall/will

Tags: tense, future-tense

I want to compare the point of the following three sentences:

1. You will never finish this book.
2. You are never finishing this book.
3. You aren't going to finish this book.

My understanding:

1. Denote only opinion (assumption) of the speaker.
2. Denote serious intention of the speaker (speaker is preventing to finish the book).
3. The same as 2.

Am I right?

Comment: "You will never finish" is the correct form in the first line. "Finished" is the past form of the verb.

Comment: @CopperKettle What about 2 and 3?

Comment: 2 and 3 seem OK to me.

Comment: @CopperKettle That is, am I correctly handed the sense of these sentences?

Comment: I'm not sure (about the 3rd sense in particular) so I'm leaving this for others to reply.

Comment: I agree 'My understanding' for the first two sentences. For the third, it *may* mean several things - an assumption that the reader is not going to finish the book (a mother telling this to her kid, sighing), an order (like *you are not gonna do this (without my permission)), and also a 'doubt'.* In fact, to me the first sentence shows the *confidence* of the speaker ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first and second seem equivalent to me. The third, to me, sounds like something you would say to someone who is trying to read/write a book in a much shorter period of time than is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In spoken language, I believe you're right about number 2 that the speaker is sounding very preventative, though, the emphasis on stress intonation used between 1 and 3 would determine it's idea, as they could both be very easily used in the same or opposing situations.

Hope this helps!